# JavaScript display child div on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, grandchild

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div onmouseover="displayDiv()">  <div id="thisIsTheDivToDisplay"></div   </div>
    <div onmouseover="displayDiv()">  <div id="thisIsTheDivToDisplay"></div>  </div>
    <div onmouseover="displayDiv()">  <div id="thisIsTheDivToDisplay"></div>  </div>
    <div onmouseover="displayDiv()">  <div id="thisIsTheDivToDisplay"></div>  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the `div` inside, when I `mouseover` it's `parent div`. But I'cant use ID's, because the number of div's is random (depends on values in database). Is there any way in JavaScript to display that only child `div` (depending on `div` I mouseover)?

Comment: Attribute `id` must be unique.

Comment: Sure - use the `this` pointer

Comment: Yes, I know, I used it only to show which div's I want to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you need to use js? it can be solved via css.
here is fiddle with working example

```
<div class="lol">
    <div>lol</div>
</div>

<div class="lol">
    <div>lol</div>
</div>

<div class="lol">
    <div>lol</div>
</div>


.lol{width:100px;height:100px; background:red;margin:10px}
.lol div{display:none}
.lol:hover div{display:block}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kpblc/4Vfra/

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I as looking for!

Comment: Indeed a better solution.

Comment: @qazerty23 glad I could help! but better set classes to elements, and style throw them. set rules directly to elements, it's not wery good.

good: .lol .lol-child{background: red}
not wery good: .lol div{background: red}